# Visual Studio 2015 not suggesting fixes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I'm on a new computer with Visual Studio 2015 and it's not suggesting fixes. When I type in a class from a namespace that doesn't exist, it's not asking me if I want to import the reference, and there is no lightbulb appearing next to the line to suggest fixes.

Comment: Hi Erica, any update for this issue? It it still blocks you, you can share more details about your project type and content of the project so that I can check for you:)

Answer (score 0):

First, please make sure you've updated VS2015 to latest VS2015 Update3. And go `Tools=>Options=>Import and Export settings=>Reset all settings=>No, just reset=>general` to reset VS settings, it may make some difference.

Then you can try:

1.Navigate to solution folder, find the hidden .vs folder, close all VS instance and delete that folder

2.Delete the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache` folder to clean the VS cache. After that, restart VS to check if it's resolved.

If the issue still exists, please run VS [safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2015) to check whether this issue comes from third-party vsx extensions. If Intellisense works well in safemode, then something broken from the extension caused the issue, disable it or uninstall it can resolve the issue.

If all above not helps, you may need to [repair VS2015](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d7d23136-dd04-42f2-888e-a3cc0e46a7c5/how-to-install-uninstall-and-repair-vs-2015-components-after-initial-install?forum=vssetup) to make it work normally.